# Merge 2 columns in pandas into one columns that have data in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I"m not sure How to word this but I'm trying to combine 2 columns say from datafram df :

```
x1  x2
NaN  3
2    2
4    2
NaN  5
8    NaN
```

so I would like to get result of

```
X
3
2
4
5
8
```

I tried to use pd.merge but this won't work. pretty new to python can you guide me which function do I need in this situation ?

Comment: So if `x1` and `x2` are both non-NaN, you want `x1`?

Comment: is your desired merge operation (logically) "max"?

Comment: yes, I would like capture the first one which is x1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from your question whether you want `x1` to dominate over `x2` (my first guess) or whether you want the maximum of both columns (@RobStarling's guess).  We can do either.  To see the difference, we'll change your frame slightly:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': {0: np.nan, 1: 2.0, 2: 4.0, 3: 1, 4: 8.0}, 'x2': {0: 3.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 5.0, 4: np.nan}})
>>> df
   x1  x2
0 NaN   3
1   2   2
2   4   2
3   1   5
4   8 NaN

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

If you want `x1` to win, we can use `where`-- we want to use `x1` wherever it's not null, and `x2` otherwise:

```
>>> df["x1"].where(~pd.isnull(df["x1"]), df["x2"])
0    3
1    2
2    4
3    1
4    8
Name: x1, dtype: float64
```

If you want the maximum of either:

```
>>> df[["x1", "x2"]].max(axis=1)
0    3
1    2
2    4
3    5
4    8
dtype: float64
```