# Combining two columns with related data into a single column (python, pandas)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am looking for the correct logic to combine two columns with related data from an .xlsx file using pandas in python.  It is similar to the post: [Merge 2 columns in pandas into one columns that have data in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406820/merge-2-columns-in-pandas-into-one-columns-that-have-data-in-python), except that I also want to transform the data as I combine the columns so it's not really a true merge of the two columns.  I want to be able to say "if column wbc_na has the value "checked" in row x, place "Not available" in row x under column wbc". Once combined, I want to drop the column" wbc_na" since "wbc" now contains all the information I need.  For example:

```
input:  
ID,wbc, wbc_na  
1,9.0,-  
2,NaN,checked  
3,10.2,-  
4,8.8,-  
5,0,checked
```

output:

```
ID,wbc  
1,9.0  
2,Not available  
3,10.2  
4,8.8  
5,Not available
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `loc` to find where column 'wbc_na' is 'checked' and for those rows assign column 'wbc' value:

```
In [18]:
df.loc[df['wbc_na'] == 'checked', 'wbc'] = 'Not available'
df
Out[18]:
   ID            wbc   wbc_na
0   1              9      -  
1   2  Not available  checked
2   3           10.2      -  
3   4            8.8      -  
4   5  Not available  checked

[5 rows x 3 columns]
In [19]:
# now drop the extra column
df.drop(labels='wbc_na', axis=1, inplace=True)
df
Out[19]:
   ID            wbc
0   1              9
1   2  Not available
2   3           10.2
3   4            8.8
4   5  Not available

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer seems to give the result I was looking for.  So the loc method is basically returning the row # correct?

Comment: `loc` performs label based selection, the [online docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) are worth looking at to understand the semantic differences between `loc`, `ix` and `iloc`, by the way you should have enough reputation to upvote now ;)

Comment: I was looking at (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) but it wasn't giving me enough info about the methods.  How exciting that I can upvote things now, I was just waiting to be able to do that.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could also a list comprehension to reassign the values in column wbc:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3,4,5], 'wbc': [9, np.nan, 10, 8, 0], 'wbc_nan': ['-', 'checked', '-', '-', 'checked']})
data['wbc'] = [(item if data['wbc_nan'][x] != 'checked' else 'Not available') for x, item in enumerate(data['wbc'])]
data = data.drop('wbc_nan', axis=1)
```

Comment: Tried this out, it also works with my real data.  Thank you for your solution.